# Confused by spark getNumPartitions and partitionBy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I saved a table which is partitioned by `channelIdVehicleId` column.

Actually, there are 933 unique values in the column and I believe it should have 933 partitions.

```
dfEnrichedTripsToPredict
.write
.partitionBy("channelIdVehicleId")
.saveAsTable("dac_dev.tmp.testPartition")
```

When I call `spark.table("dac_dev.tmp.testPartition").rdd.getNumPartitions`, it returns 29.

But it's weird when I call `show partitions dac_dev.tmp.testPartition`, it returns 933 rows. And if I check the table directory, it indeed has 933 subfolders.

I was confused by why they have different results. Which is right?

In addition, if I call `mapPartitions()` on the partitioned table, will it use 29 partitions or 933 partitions? How to make sure there are 933 partitions because I want to do calculations for every unique vehicle?

Comment: `partitionBy` function is repartitioning the data before saving it to table.

Comment: Yes, I load the table back to a dataframe. `spark.table("dac_dev.tmp.testPartition")`

Comment: There is no concept of preserving partitions when you write data out and read back it in. E.g. if you have 1000 csv files, reading them back won't produce 1000 partitions. Number of partitions generated after reading all the csvs is determined by default no of partitions config.

Comment: But even I specified to partition by channelIdVehicleId column, `val dfDemoPartition = dfDemo.repartition(col("channelIdVehicleId"))`, there are only 2 partitions. `dfDemoPartition.rdd.getNumPartitions` outputs 2. Why that happened?